# How to set a NULL value for a PostgreSQL column with 'timestamptz' data type?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to create two columns that have 'timestamptz' as data type.

The name of the first column is `created` and reflects the date when the item has been added to the table:

```
created timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
```

Now here's the issue, I need a new column that reflects when an item was modified (changed) but there is possibility that some article are never going to be changed so this column needs to start with a NULL timestamptz value or something.

```
modified timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT ...
```

I checked the Wordpress database as inspiration to see how they handle this. Wordpress uses mySQL. I noticed that they added datetime type with a value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00` for their `post_modified` that allows them to use a NOT NULL definition for the column.

Is there a way to do something similar in PostgreSQL? or is it better practice to remove NOT NULL and allow the `modified` column to stay empty until the item gets modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is it better practice to remove NOT NULL and allow the modified column to stay empty until the item gets modified

That's the right approach (at least in my opinion).

Postgres won't allow you to store invalid dates or timestamp values (which `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is)

---

If you want some value in the distant past, so that you don't need to care about `null` values and a comparison with "current" values works as expected, you can use infinity:

```
modified timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT '-infinity'
```

But I would go for a `NULL` value to indicate that the row has not been changed

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a_horse_with_no_name's answer is to rethink what you mean by "modified". If creation is a modification too then you can just keep "now" as your default.

A check for something that has been changed then becomes `modified <> created` rather than `NOT NULL`.

Comment: No, creation is not modification, only when the user will click the "edit" button in a web app for a specific item.